# What's the correct way of deploying a spring boot application with static content

Tags: java, css, spring, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot web application built with gradle that has the which is entirely JavaConfig based and has the structure shown below.

[image: File Structure]

From documentation and info out there in the web, I can simply build a jar file, drop it in any server, run the jar file and my application is up and running. 
However, when I do run the jar file directly, the application cannot locate my css, js or any of my image files. As you can see, I did duplicate the template folders when I was having an issue with Thymeleaf finding my templates. 
Here is my WebConfig class...

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");

}


@Bean
MultipartConfigElement multipartConfigElement() {
    MultiPartConfigFactory factory = new MultiPartConfigFactory();
    factory.setMaxFileSize("1024KB");
    factory.setMaxRequestSize("1024KB");
    return factory.createMultipartConfig();
}

}
```

What do I need to do to gain access to the .css and .js files in the running .jar file. Is there any extra config I need to do to make those files available in production?
When I do a run the application via gradle from the src folder location, it works fine though.

I appreciate any pointers I can get.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will find this link very helpful.  [Serving Static Web Content with Spring Boot](https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot)

> While this may not be a new revelation to those of you that have been
>   following Spring Boot since the SpringOne announcement, there is one
>   detail for which you may not be aware. Spring Boot will automatically
>   add static web resources located within any of the following
>   directories:
>
> ```
> /META-INF/resources/
> /resources/
> /static/
> /public/
> ```

Comment: I used that example earlier though. I've moved all the static content over to the resources folder and I still am not accessing the static content. For example, referencing a .js file in /resources/js/somefile.js produces not result.

Comment: @Jome Have you tried removing the AddResourceHandlers() method and seeing if that works? It looks like spring is already configuring the `/resources` in WebMvcAutoConfiguration. My configuration is almost like yours. The only difference is I have my static content in `webapp/static` rather than `webapp/resources`. I also do not override the addResourceHandlers.
I also believe that the addResourceLocations() needs to be a classpath. For instance, `addResourceLocations("classpath:/resources/")`

Comment: I've just disabled the class entirely and I am still not accessing the files. By way of curiosity, how do you reference the files from your html? Like I said, when I run the application using gradle and referencing a js file like this; "/resources/js/custom.js", the files pull through fine. Just doesnt do same when I run the built jar file standalone.

Comment: @Jome I access them using /static/test.js. One thing is that I use Maven to build a .war rather than a .jar. With the webapp folder, it suggests that you're building a .war file. I don't know if it's expecting files to be in src/main/resources.

Comment: Hi @John. I have actually gotten rid of the webapp folder and moved the files to the resources folder. I'll move them now to main/static?

Comment: I am actually building a jar file. Maybe that explains why it works with gradle and not as standalone?

Comment: Following the insight you gave around war files, I just built the app as a war file and it works well now as a standalone. I wonder why it was giving me issues though. Thanks.